# How to overload a template function for use with enums?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++14

I have a bunch of functions who all have the same name but have different arguments (some of them are templates, some aren't):

```
void f(int& a) { ... } // there are a few other arithmetic types as well
void f(bool& a) { ... }
template <class T1, class T2> void f(std::pair<T1, T2>&a) { ... } 
template <class T> void f(T& a) { ... }
// ...
```

In addition to that, I have an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
  enumVal1, enumVal2
};
```

I actually thought that if I now call `MyEnum e = enumVal1; f(e);`, it would automatically call the overload of `MyEnum`'s underlying type. It doesn't. Instead, it generates a compiler error.

Now I want to define a template function that catches all enums and calls the appropriate function.

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>{}> * = nullptr>
void f(T &a) { /* cast to std::underlying_type<T> and call f() */ }
```

Unfortanetely for some reason this creates an ambiguity with the existing `f(T& a)`.

How can I solve this problem? The solution has to be valid for all enums (but not for class enums).

I compile my code using gcc 4.9 and clang 3.5.

Comment: Try this with c++11's "enum class"

Comment: Why not put '! std::is_enum' for f(T& a) ? I think that should remove the ambiguity. I admit this is less classy solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of SFINAE doesn't provide a better versions for partial ordering but merely determines which overloads are available. That is, for enums there two equally good candidate functions of `f()` resulting in an ambiguity. The easiest way to address this ambiguity is to SFINAE both candidates to be for mutually exclusive sets of types:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<T>{}> * = nullptr>
void f(T &a) {
    // version not applicable for enums
}
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>{}> * = nullptr>
void f(T &a) {
    /* cast to std::underlying_type<T> and call f() */
}
```

This does **not** solve your original problem, though, as enumerator are no lvalues. Note that your original problem canb be solved by *not* taking a `T&` as argument but rather taking a `T`, a `T const&` or possibly a `T&&`: `enum`s *do* convert to an underlying type but an enumerator tag is not an lvalue and can't be bound to a non-`const` reference.

Unless there is a good reason not to, I'd probably go with just one overload:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& a) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I need to change the parameter within `f`. Is this possible with `T&&` or `T const&`?

Comment: You cannot changed the referenced object if it is referencing a constant. That is for `T const&` it can never be changed and for `T&&` it can be changed when the passed argument isn't a `const` lvalue. If you need to change the parameter the easiest approach is to pass the argument by value but it won't change the entity passed in: that is impossible for enumerator tags any as they are clearly immutable.

Comment: Based on the comment to the other answer you are not really passing enumerator tags as in your question. In that case you probably want different implementation to extract/restore the enum value to the underlying type using the two SFINAE function. That can be made to work with enum classes by explicitly converting.

Answer (score 1):

The functions `f` only accept (non const) references:

```
int main() {
    auto e = enumVal1;
    f(e);
    return 0;
}
```

Hence `f(enumVal1)` fails.

Comment: You're right, but this was just an example. In my real application, it's more like `MyEnum e = enumVal1; f(e);`